# Overload resolution when passing in a function template to another function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, template-function

I have the following code :

```
template<typename T>
void bar(int x, T y)
{
}

void baz(int x, int y)
{
}

template<typename T0, typename T1>
void foo(void k(T0, T1), T1 t)
{
}

int main()
{
  foo(baz, 10); // OK
  foo(bar, 10); // ERROR
  return 0;
}
```

Overload resolution for `foo` works correctly when passing in `baz`. However, when passing in the function template `bar`, the compiler is unable to infer the template argument `T0` of `foo`, even though there is only one `bar` in the scope, and its first argument is completely resolved to `int`. How do I write the function template `foo` such that calls like `foo(bar, 10)` can be resolved by the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

14.8.2.1/6 (*Deducing template arguments from a function call*) answers this:

> When `P` is a function type, pointer to function type, or pointer to member function type:
>
> - If the argument is an overload set containing one or more function templates, the parameter is treated as a non-deduced context.

In your case, `bar` is a function template, and thus the argument `k` is of function type whose overload set contains function templates. Thus the template argument for `bar<T>` is not deducible.

As a practical reasons for this, consider that `foo(bar<int>, 10)` and `foo(bar<long>, 10)` are both entirely viable calls, and the choice will not be made for you implicitly. Remember that the type of an integer literal depends on the *value*, and it would be weird if `foo(bar, 10)` and `foo(bar, 100000000)` produced different template specializations.

Comment: Yes, I understand the reasons for why my current example is non-deducible. My question was on how to re-write the function template `foo`? In other words is there some help I can provide the compiler at the function definition site rather than the call site so that this can work? Function templates as arguments is not unprecedented. For instance, `std::endl` is a function template.

Comment: @keveman "_For instance, std::endl is a function template._" But `basic_ostream::operator<<` is not!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
  void (&b)(int,int) = bar;
  foo(b, 10);
```